# Enabling memcache on Mac OSX with stock apache and php5

Tags: macos, memcached

I cannot for the life of me figure out how I can enable memcache on Mac OSX to work w/ apache.  I have installed memcache and can verify that it is working via the php command line.

The following command:

```
php --ri memcache
```

reports that memcache is supported.

However, if I load a local test script that executes phpinfo() in my browser, it does not report that memcahe is installed.  Running a script in my browser that instantiates a new memcache object reports:

```
Fatal error: Class ‘Memcache’ not found
```

I have edited php.ini and added extensions=memcache.so

I have restarted apache by going to System Preferences->Sharing and disabling and enabling  Web Sharing. I have even tried restarting apache from the command line w/ sudo apachectl restart.

What could I be missing that is preventing php from recognizing memcache when executed through the browser?

Thanks!

Comment: I have exact same issue..and so many threads but not a running solution!

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have the memcache.so extension installed in a `*/no-debug-non-zts-*` directory which is sometimes painful (same on Linux) and the php.ini may not look in this directory.  You can either change the extensions directory in you php.ini (which may break other things) or better create a symlink to the memcache.so file in the `*/no-debug-non-zts-*` dir.

In my case, this was:

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/memcache.so /usr/lib64/php/modules/memcache.so
```

Further to this check the permissions on the memcache.so file and ensure it is executable (755), in my case, this was:

```
chmod 755 /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/memcache.so
```

Hope that helps and that is my last suggestion :)

Comment: This helped me--the issue is due to various ways I've installed things on my mac (brew mostly, but not exclusively). The PHP CLI had memcached loaded, but under mod_php (apache) it was using a different directory to look for extensions. You can fix this by copying/symlinking the file. Check the "extension_dir" value in `php -i` vs `phpinfo()` under apache.

Comment: Mine is in /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_socache_memcache.so . In CLI everything works fine but Apache fail to load memcache any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Sure seems like the command line php and mod_php are using different versions of php.ini.

Answer (score -1):

What are you using memcache for?  How are you initiating it?  Have you got memcached running on the machine as well?

This is not specifically a mac answer, but hopefully it will set you along the run route, apologies if this is covering the obvious.

You need memcached running either on the mac or on another machine that the mac can access on the memcached port.

There is a specific doc here on memcached on Mac - http://memcached.darwinports.com/

Remember you also need to configure php to use memcache for whatever you want memcache to cache, e.g. change the relevant PHP settings, for example using memcache to handle sessions:

session.save_handler = files 

change to:

session.save_handler = memcache

session.save_path="tcp://:11211?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=2"

Hopes this helps in some way.

http://www.of-networks.co.uk

Comment: thanks, but i'm looking for an answer that specifically addresses my mac osx issue. i believe i am missing a configuration somewhere in either apache or php. on my production servers, which are running ubuntu, i have successfully installed memcached for both command line and web use.

Comment: Hi Halbet

Apparently comments can only be 600 characters (not good if you ramble).  Trying to add another answer.

Comment: This doesn't address the actual issue the OP is asking. It's clear that he's trying to use the memcache client and PHP under apache can't find it (but it's installed because the CLI can find it).